# How to build a json object of a Mongoid object with children?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have two simple classes

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type:String
  has_many :members
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band
end
```

After I have created two object for test purposes

```
Band.create(title: 'New Band')
Band.members.create(name: 'New Member')
```

I got next db state:

```
> db.bands.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "title" : "New Band" }
> db.members.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "New Member", "band_id" : ObjectId("...") }
```

When I try to build json object of Band object I get data without children:

```
{"_id":"...","title":"New Band"}
```

But I need something like that:

```
{"_id":"...","title":"New Band", "members" : {"_id":"...","title":"New Member"}}
```

How to build json with children??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a_band = Band.last
a_band.as_json(methods: [:members])
```

Mongoid auto-generates helper methods for your relations, and you can include these methods when you build your JSON object.  You can use `a_band.members` to fetch the band's members out of the db, so you can include that method in your JSON object, like any other method on the model.

Comment: One warning on this: It seems all of the `.as_json()` options get passed on to any nested objects, such that if you had `a_band.as_json(only: [:name], methods: [:members])`, then the members would only contain the `name` property too.  If you wanted their age, for example, you would have to manually include that field, like `a_band.as_json(only: [:name, :age], methods: [:members])`

Answer (score 5):

You can override `serializable_hash`:

```
class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band

  def serializable_hash(options={})
    {
      id: id,
      name: name
    }
  end
end

class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  has_many :members

  def serializable_hash(options={})
    {
      id: id,
      title: title,
      members: members.inject([]) { |acc, m| acc << m.serializable_hash; acc }
    }
  end  
end
```

Suppose you have a band with a member:

```
band = Band.create(title: 'New Band')
band.members.create(name: 'New Member')
```

In that case `band.to_json` will return you something like that:

```
"{\"id\":...,\"title\":\"New Band\",\"members\":[{\"id\":...,\"name\":\"New Member\"}]}"
```

Comment: You don't have to duplicate `serializable_hash`. Just call super and add the new members. `def serializable_hash(options={}); hash = super(options); hash[:members] = ...; hash; end`